# Where is the API documentation for boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

The [user guide](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/index.html#service-feature-guides) for [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) refers high-level Resources and low-level clients.  They are accessed by passing the name of the service to `boto3.resource` and `boto3.client`, respectively.

This might seem kind of pedantic - I could probably make reasonable guesses as to the names of each resource or client - but *where* do I find a list of available resources?  Unless I missed something, it doesn't appear to be in the User Guide.  And I'm not finding a more detailed API reference anywhere.

Once I do have a resource (like EC2) - where do I find documentation on *what* I can do with it?  There are some examples [here in the user guide](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/migrationec2.html), but they appear to be a subset.

This leaves me feeling like my only option is to inspect objects on the REPL for plausible looking method names.

Am I missing something here?  How do people actually use this library?

Comment: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/services/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation is here:

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Available resources are generated dynamically.  If you just try to create a bogus one, you should be able to see which top-level resources are currently available in the error message:

```
>>> boto3.resource('potato')
ResourceNotExistsError: The 'potato' resource does not exist.
The available resources are:
   - cloudformation
   - cloudwatch
   - dynamodb
   - ec2
   - glacier
   - iam
   - opsworks
   - s3
   - sns
   - sqs

>>> boto3.client('bogus')
UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'bogus'. Valid service names are: acm, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, autoscaling, batch, budgets, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, codestar, cognito-identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, config, cur, datapipeline, devicefarm, directconnect, discovery, dms, ds, dynamodb, dynamodbstreams, ec2, ecr, ecs, efs, elasticache, elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, firehose, gamelift, glacier, health, iam, importexport, inspector, iot, iot-data, kinesis, kinesisanalytics, kms, lambda, lex-models, lex-runtime, lightsail, logs, machinelearning, marketplacecommerceanalytics, meteringmarketplace, mturk, opsworks, opsworkscm, organizations, pinpoint, polly, rds, redshift, rekognition, resourcegroupstaggingapi, route53, route53domains, s3, sdb, servicecatalog, ses, shield, sms, snowball, sns, sqs, ssm, stepfunctions, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, waf, waf-regional, workdocs, workspaces, xray
```

What you can actually do with a client is also [generated dynamically, from json files](https://github.com/boto/boto3/tree/develop/boto3/data).  For example here is the service description for [Amazon Glacier](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/data/glacier/2012-06-01/resources-1.json).

A client can also tell you the available subresources, using this method:

```
>>> glacier = boto3.resource('glacier')
>>> glacier.get_available_subresources()
['Account', 'Archive', 'Job', 'MultipartUpload', 'Notification', 'Vault']
```

The parameters necessary to instantiate a `glacier.Archive()`, for example, are [clearly documented](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/services/glacier.html#archive).  The docs are quite good, but it is also pretty easy to discern the same information from reading the [service description](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/60681e878dcac31c3771c3c2f272a65f57cf56d8/boto3/data/glacier/2012-06-01/resources-1.json#L101-L149) files directly.

Comment: Ah - there it was, right under my nose in 'Available Services'.  Thanks!